# error in php date function using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead
```

I received this error from my php page.I used codeigniter as framework. Here it is the code I used to create date:

```
$datestring = "%d/%m/%Y - %h:%i %a";
$time = time();

$data['curr_time'] = mdate($datestring, $time);
```

Where is the error?

Comment: The error is not having read the error message - it tells you what the problem is and how to fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have php 5.3.
Anyway , the solution is to define the timezone to php by adding to your php files the next code before using any time/date function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

or , a better solution , editing your php.ini file and adding:

> date.timezone = "America/Anchorage"

`America/Anchorage` is the timezone , use the one that is relevant to you from the list:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code in your index.php file

```
if( !ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}
```